# How to get a small string data from a website.

Tags: android, json, web

Can I retrieve a string data from a website of my own.? Actually I got an idea to prompt user to update my app if there is any new version available in the market.
For this, I have a website with the app link on it. Each time I update my app, I will put a version string on the website. Now I want to get that string data somehow and compare it with my version code. If there is any difference between both of the, the user will be prompted for update.

For Example if I have my app version code as 21 and the website string has data 22 then that means a new update of my app is available and user shall be prompted to download it. Can anyone please help me with this idea by telling me hopw to put that string data to website and how to retrieve that data in my android app.?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: I think you should go for default Play Store. It will automatically give notification if new update (new release) of your application in market. What you want to do is already provided by google, then why do you want to invent your own?

Comment: Google Play does the update part for you, if you are goind to put up your app on Play Store. Or If you are not using Play Store, You can connect to the website and get the data.. You can do this by JSoup for example, If you know where in the page will the data be stored...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using same feature you are looking for. I called networkUpdate() on OnCreate of my MainActivity.

1. This function created separated thread and get latest version number online.
2. Get version number of this binary
3. Display custom message  in toast (reminder of new version)

Online text file

```
{"version":"1.2","message":"News version of XXX is available. Please download at Google Play"}
```

The source code in android

```
    private Handler m_handler;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...............

    m_handler = new Handler();  //for main thread
    networkUpdate();
    }

private void networkUpdate(){ 


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

          @Override 
          public void run() { //heavy loading 
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              try {
                  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
                            "http://xxx/version.txt");
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            JsonNode networkJson =  mapper.readTree(retSrc);
            PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            String version = pInfo.versionName;
            String networkVersion = networkJson.path("version").textValue();
            if(Float.valueOf(version) < Float.valueOf(networkVersion)){
                m_updateMessage = networkJson.path("message").textValue();
            }
            System.out.println(version + "v "+ networkVersion + " m " +networkJson.path("message").textValue());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("network update", "read version json", e);
            }
              m_handler.post(new Runnable() {

          public void run() { //main thread

              if(m_updateMessage != null){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, m_updateMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }

          } }); } }); t.start();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are publishing your app in Google Play, then Google Play will handle it for you.

But if you are not going thru some app store which has this update mechanism built in, then you can have a static page hosted on any web server(say Apache), and connect to that page using URLs and retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, by adding a Checking Updates WebService on your site.
 when your you want to check any update on your application , your application will call the Method from that web service , which in return Returns the version, then you can compare with that and perform Update,